# Prompting and Passing

Tags: python

I am getting an error when I write this code. How do I rewrite this that it works? I am following the book and it is telling as it is.
from sys import argv

```
script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions."
print "Do you like me %s?" % user_name
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print "Where do you live %s?" % user_name
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print "What kind of computer do you have?"
computer = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright, so you said %r about liking me. 
You live in %r. Not sure where that is. 
And you have a %r computer. Nice. 
""" % (likes, lives, computer)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python-files\ex14.py", line 5, in <module>
    script, user_name = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: Try `print(argv)`. It seems that there are not as many values as you think there are.

Comment: This script requires exactly one argument. Are you calling it with one argument? (e.g. `python C:\python-files\ex14.py syeed`)